How to obtain information from HAPI_parmInfo on the folder collapse status?
I am learning how the HoudiniEngine for Maya is written (https://github.com/Onekke/scs-houdini-engine-for-maya). Currently, I am wondering if there is a possibility how to obtain the information on whether the folder is collapsed by default or not when importing an asset from Houdini using the HoudiniEngine API.
The documentation of HoudiniEngine for Maya plugin (https://www.sidefx.com/docs/houdini/maya/) is not sufficient when it comes to how the code is structured to create the bridge between Houdini API and Maya API. In fact, the documentation is non-existent (https://www.sidefx.com/docs/houdini/maya/code.html) as the link only summarizes what is done in each source file and not how the plugin is layered and what patterns it uses (from what I have seen in the code I doubt it uses any).
From what I could deduce, the tags assigned to a folder parm in Houdini can be accessed in the Util.C method 'static void getParmTags(...)'. Unfortunately, this yields no results for folder parameters.
I attempted to call this method and acquire the tags in the SynAttribute.C in the CreateAttrOperation::pushFolder(..) operation that is called when the parameters are parsed. Unfortunately, no tags we acquired using this approach.
void CreateAttrOperation::pushFolder(const HAPI_ParmInfo &parmInfo){
MFnCompoundAttribute *attrFn = NULL;
bool invisible               = myInvisibles.back() || parmInfo.invisible;

// MFnCompoundAttribute* parentAttrFn = myAttrFns.back();
// const HAPI_ParmInfo* &parentParmInfo = myParentParmInfos.back();

if (!invisible)
{
    attrFn = new MFnCompoundAttribute();

    MString attrName = Util::getAttrNameFromParm(parmInfo);
    MString niceName = Util::HAPIString(parmInfo.labelSH);

    attrFn->create(attrName, attrName);
    attrFn->setNiceNameOverride(niceName);

    std::vector<MString> tagNames;
    std::vector<MString> tagValues;
 
    getParmTags(myNodeInfo, parmInfo, tagNames, tagValues);

    MGlobal::displayInfo("Folder");
    MGlobal::displayInfo( Util::HAPIString(parmInfo.nameSH));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < tagNames.size(); i++)
    {
        MGlobal::displayInfo(tagNames[i]);
        MGlobal::displayInfo(tagValues[i]);

    }
    MGlobal::displayInfo("");
}

myAttrFns.push_back(attrFn);
myInvisibles.push_back(invisible);
myParentParmInfos.push_back(&parmInfo);}

How would I acquire the tag information from folder parameters?
Thank you kindly for your time and answers.
